# unwanted concatenation jquery

Tags: jquery, loops, concatenation

I have a form which i need to add an insurance cost (0.30 per stamp) I'm using a .each to find the book size (amount of stamps) and also the same loop to find the quantity of books.

My logic is to get the size of the book * quantity of books for each selected row of the table, then combine the result into a single number.

The results are always multiple, concatenated numbers rather then returning a single combined number.

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

      $('select').change(function(){

        $(this).parent().parent().addClass('selected');

        });

      $( "#target" ).submit(function( event ) {

        event.preventDefault();

var value = 0;

        $(".selected").each(function() {

          var size = parseFloat($(".selected .book_size").text(), 10);

          var qty = parseFloat($(".selected .stamps_qty").val(), 10);


        value += qty * size;

        console.log(value * 0.3);

        });

    });


    }); // jquery noConflict


<FORM id = "target">
<TR>
            <TD class = "book_size">5</TD>
              <SELECT class = "stamps_qty">
                <option value=0>0
                <option value=1>1
                <option value=2>2
            </SELECT>
    </TR>
    <TR>
            <TD class = "book_size">10</TD>
              <SELECT class = "stamps_qty">
                <option value=0>0
                <option value=1>1
                <option value=2>2
            </SELECT>
    <TD class = "book_size">30</TD>
              <SELECT class = "stamps_qty">
                <option value=0>0
                <option value=1>1
                <option value=2>2
            </SELECT>
    </TR>
</FORM>
```

Comment: provide some demo please!

Comment: Your html is completely messed up

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/o2818rg4/2/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your script html is correct, you need to find the related elements(size & qty)

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $("#target").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var value = 0;
    $(".stamps_qty").each(function() {
      var qty = parseFloat($(this).val(), 10);
      if (qty) {
        var size = parseFloat($(this).parent().prev(".book_size").text(), 10);
        value += (qty * size);
      }
    });
  });
}); // jquery noConflict
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<FORM id="target">
  <table>
    <TR>
      <TD class="book_size">5</TD>
      <td>
        <SELECT class="stamps_qty">
          <option value=0>0</option>
          <option value=1>1</option>
          <option value=2>2</option>
        </SELECT>
      </td>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD class="book_size">10</TD>
      <td>
        <SELECT class="stamps_qty">
          <option value=0>0</option>
          <option value=1>1</option>
          <option value=2>2</option>
        </SELECT>
      </td>
    </TR>
    <TD class="book_size">30</TD>
    <td>
      <SELECT class="stamps_qty">
        <option value=0>0</option>
        <option value=1>1</option>
        <option value=2>2</option>
      </SELECT>
    </td>
    </TR>
  </table>
  <input type="submit" />
</FORM>
```

---

If you still want to use the `selected` class

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('select').change(function(){
        $(this).closest('tr').addClass('selected');
    });

    $("#target").submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var value = 0;
        $(".selected").each(function () {
            var qty = parseFloat($(this).find(".stamps_qty").val(), 10);
            if (qty) {
                var size = parseFloat($(this).find(".book_size").text(), 10);
                value += (qty * size);
            }
        });
        console.log(value, value * .3)
    });
}); // jquery noConflict
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/o2818rg4/3/)

Comment: Great, im using the second code. Its a little longer but works. In the first code Prev() wasnt working for me. My sample code has been simplified & ".book_size" is not the direct predecessor.